# R compare date from one column with dates in many columns

Tags: r, date, if-statement, compare

I have a dataset with 8 columns, 7 columns out of 8 are date columns. I need to compare the date in one column say `ReferenceDate` with dates in other columns say `DateCol1, DateCol2, DateCol3, DateCol4, DateCol5, DateCol6, DateCol7`

```
ID   DateCol1   DateCol2   DateCol3   DateCol4   ReferenceDate DateCol5   DateCol6   DateCol7
12  2000-11-03  2007-05-17 2003-07-11 2014-03-19 2000-07-11    1999-10-06 2015-06-29 2014-07-06 
17  2015-12-16  2017-07-26 2015-01-13 2020-01-30 2015-03-08    2007-07-30 2020-05-21 2010-10-09 
19  2003-03-06  2011-02-23 2001-09-18 2001-04-05 2013-05-17    1999-10-02 2004-08-26 2019-04-15 
23  2002-10-06  2019-03-12 1999-04-19 2008-04-03 2006-11-20    2000-11-15 2010-07-22 1999-05-27 
22  2019-05-19  2014-11-17 2001-03-24 2003-07-03 2001-04-02    2017-06-03 2016-09-21 2013-07-13
```

My goal is to create a column `Yes/No` value that indicates if the the date in `ReferenceDate` column was earlier or later than any of the dates in the 7 other date columns.

```
ID   DateCol1   DateCol2   DateCol3   DateCol4   ReferenceDate DateCol5   DateCol6   DateCol7    Status
12  2000-11-03  2007-05-17 2003-07-11 2014-03-19 2000-07-11    1999-10-06 2015-06-29 2014-07-06  Yes (DateCol5 earlier than Reference Date)
17  2015-12-16  2017-07-26 2015-01-13 2020-01-30 2015-03-08    2007-07-30 2020-05-21 2010-10-09  Yes (DateCol5 earlier than Reference Date)
19  2003-03-06  1981-02-23 2001-09-18 2001-04-05 2013-05-17    1999-10-02 2004-08-26 2019-04-15  Yes (DateCol2 earlier than Reference Date)
23  1992-10-06  2019-03-12 1999-04-19 2008-04-03 2006-11-20    2000-11-15 2010-07-22 1999-05-27  Yes (DateCol1 earlier than Reference Date)
22  2019-05-19  2014-11-17 2001-03-24 2003-07-03 2001-04-02    2017-06-03 2016-09-21 2013-07-13  No
```

I suppose I could do this using a lot of nested ifelse, but I would just go insane. I need some help how to accomplish this more efficiently. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The 'ReferenceDate' is input and 'expected' are not the same esp the last one

Comment: Did you meant `nm1 <- grep('^DateCol', names(df1), value = TRUE);c("No", "Yes")[(rowSums(df1[nm1] > df1$ReferenceDate) != 0) + 1]`

Comment: @akrun I think OP had a typo in the last line. Your solution would work for sure.

Comment: @akrun, you are correct. I fixed this now. Also I would prefer an approach without grep function because the Date columns in the actual dataset do not have a repeating pattern in their column names. I used a column name with repeating pattern for convenience in this example.

Comment: @bison2178 Is the Date columns in a range i.e. from column 3 to last column or so

Comment: @akrun, no the 7 date columns are scattered randomly in the dataset and they have random column names. I guess I could subset the dataset for only those specific columns and apply your solution

Comment: I added an option `nm1 <- setdiff(names(df1), c("ID", "ReferenceDate"))` suggesting to select all columns except the 'ID' and 'ReferenceDate' (assuming all others are the DateCols

Comment: For the last row `DateCol3` is earlier than Reference Date so it should be 'Yes' as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `rowSums` would be to `select` the 'Date' columns, do a comparison with 'ReferenceDate' column, check whether the `rowSums` output is not equal to 0, convert the logical to numeric index (add 1) and use that to replace the values with 'Yes', 'No'

```
nm1 <- grep('^DateCol', names(df1), value = TRUE)
```

Or if the column names are not 'DateCol' as patterns, may be

```
nm1 <- setdiff(names(df1), c("ID", "ReferenceDate"))
df1$flag <- c("No", "Yes")[(rowSums(df1[nm1] > df1$ReferenceDate) != 0) + 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this might help

```
df$Status <- ifelse(rowSums(sapply(df[-1], `<`, df$ReferenceDate)) > 0, "Yes", "No")
```

which gives (no idea why the last line of desired output gives "No")

```
> df
  ID   DateCol1   DateCol2   DateCol3   DateCol4 ReferenceDate   DateCol5
1 12 2000-11-03 2007-05-17 2003-07-11 2014-03-19    2000-07-11 1999-10-06
2 17 2015-12-16 2017-07-26 2015-01-13 2020-01-30    2015-03-08 2007-07-30
3 19 2003-03-06 2011-02-23 2001-09-18 2001-04-05    2013-05-17 1999-10-02
4 23 2002-10-06 2019-03-12 1999-04-19 2008-04-03    2006-11-20 2000-11-15
5 22 2003-05-19 2014-11-17 2001-03-24 2003-07-03    2014-04-02 2017-06-03
    DateCol6   DateCol7 Status
1 2015-06-29 2014-07-06    Yes
2 2020-05-21 2010-10-09    Yes
3 2004-08-26 2019-04-15    Yes
4 2010-07-22 1999-05-27    Yes
5 2016-09-21 2013-07-13    Yes
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c(12L, 17L, 19L, 23L, 22L), DateCol1 = structure(c(11264,
16785, 12117, 11966, 12191), class = "Date"), DateCol2 = structure(c(13650,
17373, 15028, 17967, 16391), class = "Date"), DateCol3 = structure(c(12244,
16448, 11583, 10700, 11405), class = "Date"), DateCol4 = structure(c(16148,
18291, 11417, 13972, 12236), class = "Date"), ReferenceDate = structure(c(11149,
16502, 15842, 13472, 16162), class = "Date"), DateCol5 = structure(c(10870,
13724, 10866, 11276, 17320), class = "Date"), DateCol6 = structure(c(16615,
18403, 12656, 14812, 17065), class = "Date"), DateCol7 = structure(c(16257,
14891, 18001, 10738, 15899), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA,
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`'s `rowwise` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Status = if(any(c_across(starts_with('DateCol')) < ReferenceDate)) 
                  'Yes' else 'No') -> result

result
```